# FOP How to get the dimensions of the body in each page of the PDF

Tags: java, pdf, xsl-fo, apache-fop

I am using FOP to render XSL-FO into PDF. The XSL-FO will be supplied by a third party and it can render into multiple pages and the layout of each page can be different. By using FOP API, can i get the dimension of the body of the each page that is rendered?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know if you can do this using the FOP API, however since XSL-FO is well-formed XML, you can just write a small stylesheet that reads the page dimensions from the page-masters defined for the page-sequences you're interested in.